# Can I invoke the draw() function on a Datatablevue3 component?

Tags: ajax, datatables, vuejs3, server-side

I'm building an app and I want to use Datatables with Vue 3 and bootstrap 5 with the serverside option. I'll be using Datatables in a lot of pages and I don't want to get the data independently and populate the table using the data option. It would mean that I'll have to load the entire data into the clientside.

```
script setup>
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap'
import { onMounted, ref} from 'vue'
import DataTableLib from 'datatables.net-bs5'
import DatatablesVue from 'datatables.net-vue3'
import Buttons from 'datatables.net-buttons-bs5'
import ButtonsHtml5 from 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5'
import Print from 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print'
import PdfMake from 'pdfmake'
import PdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts'
import KeyTable from 'datatables.net-keytable-bs5'
import FixedHeader from 'datatables.net-fixedheader-bs5'
import Select from 'datatables.net-select-bs5'
import 'datatables.net-responsive-bs5'
import JSZip from 'jszip'
import JsonData from '../helpers/data.json'
window.JSZip = JSZip

DatatablesVue.use(DataTableLib)
DatatablesVue.use(PdfMake)
DatatablesVue.use(FixedHeader)
DatatablesVue.use(KeyTable)
DatatablesVue.use(Select)
DatatablesVue.use(ButtonsHtml5)

const options = {
    serverSide: true,
    select: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    keys: true,
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,   
    lengthMenu: [30, 50, 100, 150]
}

const columns = [
    //......
]

<?script>

<template>
    <div class="container mt-5 table-responsive">
     <DatatablesVue
         :options="options"
         ajax="/api/data"
         :columns="columns"   
         class="table table-striped display table-compact">
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Phone No.</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Jobs</th>
              <th>Paid</th>
              <th>Created at</th>
             <th>Actions</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody></tbody>
         <tfoot class="fw-bolder text-primary">
           <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
        </tfoot>
     </DatatablesVue>
   </div>
</template>
```

In a previous app I did with datatables I used the draw() function to dynamically display the latest records on the table(I could conveniently call the functions after different events. It was just beautiful) But with the Datatablevue3 component, DatatableVue.draw() is not a function.

How can I call a function that makes the Ajax call to refresh the data of the table?